# Iphone app homescreen tableview deconstruction

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, imdb

Can anyone explain how the tableview in Imdb [iphone homescreen](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1ODY0NDIwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzUzMDYwOA@@._V1.jpg) is implemented ? here is the structure, if anyone havnt seen it

---

imdb logo -- searchbar

---

UIPageView

---

3 buttons movies -- tv -- celebs

---

table view with 2 cells --> 
1st cell (Top News) different from the second (Showtimes)

---

then here is a thick line
--> is this line a modified section header ?

---

a table view with 3 cells 
with images on the left

---

again the the thick line

---

then again table view with cells
without any images

---

I have posted this question on assumption, that more than one tableview has been used..
Is there a single tableview in this homescreen or have they used more than one table view ?

how is the thick line made here ?
any help is appreciated :) thanks

Comment: What do you really want to know ??

Comment: 1 tableview or multiple tableviews ? then how the tableview is implemented ?

Comment: 1 tableview is more than enough... The separator can be applied after an interval of three cells or so ....

Comment: any idea on how the separator is implemented ?

Comment: TBH I think it's a 'plain' `UIScrollView`

Comment: @basvk you mean every cell is a UIButton just added in a way to look like tableView ?

Comment: @raw3d: Yeah, why not? The scrollview isn't very long and using a tableview (e.g. dequeueing instances) doesn't give you any (big) advantages above a plain scrollview. And using a plain UIScrollView is easier to set up too > not struggling with `UITableViewDataSource`

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the default separator style for the `UITableView`:

`[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];`

Then add the image of the separator accordingly to the **indexpath** of the cell after/before which you want the separator line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` using :

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
UIImageView *separator = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview: separator];
}
```

Also check these links for further details :

http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2012/01/separator-cells-for-uitableview/#disqus_thread

[iPhone + UITableView + place an image for separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227420/iphone-uitableview-place-an-image-for-separator)

Any doubts please ask .Thanks .

Comment: this wil change the separator for all the cells ..but I need the separator to be place at particular index only..

Comment: Please read the line where I have mentioned indexpath.row :)  You have to make changes there ...

Answer (score 0):

@raw3d- the thick line can be section with image(thickline image).

and i dont think so they have used different tableview ,they may have used tableview with section and with different cell for different section.

Hope this link will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196734/creating-grouped-uitableview-with-different-cell-types)